# further automation of grunt-require

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, gruntjs

Short and concise question.

To have requirejs do it's job i need to add **[code*]** ahead of any class I make.

```
 define(function(require, exports, module) {
    'use strict';
```

Is there any straight forward way to automatically add this ahead of any .js file before I do task:require?
(I don't know if it might change your answer, but I also use coffeescript with this setup)

Comment: It would be good if you could clarify a couple of things: Are you referring to the requirejs optimiser task (grunt-contrib-requirejs)? How are you able to to use requirejs in your application if your modules have not been already defined in the AMD format?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `onBuildWrite` option of [Require's optimizer](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js):

```
onBuildWrite: function (modName, path, contents) {
    return "'use strict'\n" + contents;
}
```

This will include 'use strict' before each module's define function.
If you'd like to place it inside of the define call I suggest using a regex to select `define(...){` and then replace this with `define(...){ + "'use strict'\n"`